# Call parameterized Jenkins pipeline from another pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

There is any way to trigger a pipeline job from another pipeline with parameters, i already tried

```
build job: '/myjob', parameters: [string(name: 'param1', value:'val1')], wait: false
```

also tried

```
build job: 'myjob', parameters: [string(name: 'param1', value:'val1')], wait: false
```

and

```
build job: 'myjob', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'param1', value: 'val1']], wait: false
```

with no luck, it says:

> Item type does not support parameters

Comment: Are you sur your pipeline 'myjob' is located at root path ? if both pipelines are in same view you can build the second just with the name : build job: 'myjob'

Comment: i tried both ways, using myjob and /myjob on every scenario it always says *Item type does not support parameters* even when i have the 'myjob' pipeline parameterized

Comment: try this line : build job: 'myjob', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'param1', value: 'val1']]

Comment: also tried didnt work, will update main question to reflect all tries, thanks

Comment: can you show me a screenshot of your pipeline with parameters declaration ? and a screenshot of the "build with params" page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since the subjob was another multibranch pipeline project i needed to specify the branch i wanted to run so with

```
build job: 'myjob/master', parameters: [string(name: 'param1', value:'val1')], wait: false
```

it now works

Comment: can this work with boolean parameters? can't seem to get that working

Answer (score 1):

The below worked for me in order to pass parameters "test_1" and "test_2" from pipeline "master" to pipeline "sub-1"

In the master pipeline

```
build job: 'sub-1', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'test_1', value: 'nameValue'], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'test_2', value: 'valueValue']], wait: true
```

In the sub pipeline "sub-1" use by referencing the "params" variable

```
node {
   echo params.test_1
   echo params.test_2
}
```

Reference:

https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/221400287-How-to-pass-parameter-to-downstream-job-in-Pipeline-job-

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Jenkins job / pipeline structure, you should prefix the job with "../" e.g.:

```
build job: '../myjob/master', parameters: [string(name: 'param1', value:'val1')], wait: false
```