# How to call a Pipeline job from another pipeline job in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have two Pipeline jobs in Jenkins. I need to call my CD pipeline once CI pipeline is success.
Also i need to pass some values from first pipeline to my second pipeline

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call parameterized Jenkins pipeline from another pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007810/call-parameterized-jenkins-pipeline-from-another-pipeline)

Comment: no. i need to call one pipeline from another pipeline

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call another job(whether it is a pipeline job or not), you can do it like this:

```
stage ('Invoke_pipelineA w params') {
            steps {
                build job: 'pipelineA', parameters: [
                string(name: 'param1', value: "value1")
                ]
            }
}
stage ('Invoke_pipelineB without params') {
            steps {
                build job: 'pipelineA'
            }
}
```

Comment: can i use call the value directly in my second pipeline. Like param1

Comment: How can use the value in my second pipeline